# Прозрачный курсор после скролла | IOS

Tags: javascript, ios

Заметил странный баг, но не знаю как его исправить. Если прокручивать мимо элемента (оверскроллинг), и в момент, когда прокрутка восстанавливает исходное состояние, программно сфокусировать инпут, то цвет курсора прозрачный.

У меня есть список элементов, и в начале есть поиск, который отображает другой список при нажатии на него. И получается, что если на него поставить фокус сразу после прокрутки, то курсора просто не видно.

Сайт запускается через WKWebView, поэтому есть доступ к нативному коду при необходимости.

Пытался переключить overflow по клику.

Пробовал переключать -webkit-overflow-scrolling.

Я попытался принудительно установить **tintColor ** в WKWebView.

Меняйте способы нажатия на блок: клик, тачстарт, тачэнд.

Пытался принудительно перерисовать document.clientWidth.

Что у меня есть под переключателем:

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; 

document.body.style.overflow = "авто";

document.body.style.setProperty("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "auto");

document.body.style.setProperty("-webkit-overflow-scrolling", "touch");
```

**UPD:** Сделал воспроизводимый пример. Если быстро прокрутить в самый низ и когда серый блок поднимется над инпутом (я называю это состояние "bounced"), то при нажатии на ввод у вас не будет курсора.

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 50vh;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: visible;
    max-height: 400px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
}
.fake-content {
  min-height: 2000px;
    background: grey;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
  position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    min-height: 80px;
}
body {overflow: hidden; margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='fake-content'></div>
  </div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```